# Slickgrid CollapseExpand Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I'm using the slickgrid example 5 for collapsing([this one](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example5-collapsing.html))

I've implemented this feature for my project but the collapse and expand icons have stopped working, like nothing is happening when i'm clicking on the collapse or expand button. Rows/Child rows stay as they are rendered. I tried to look into the code in order to find any events are bounded but couldn't.

So do I've to implement custom events to handle expand/collapse?

Any reference would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it happens when the filter has not been setup on dataView or the dataView change events are missing:

So first make sure the dataView has a filter setup:

```
dataView.setFilter(myFilter);
```

and then don't forget the listeners

```
// Make the grid respond to DataView change events.
dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
  grid.updateRowCount();
  grid.render();
});

dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
  grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
  grid.render();
});
```